# Laravel Method [where] does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5

what did i do is creating this vies for delete function according to its trainee_id.see the screenshot.
[image]
Controller segment is like this

```
public function admin_destroy($trainee_id)
{
    UserFeedbackController::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->delete();
    return back(); 
}
```

Route like this

`Route::get('DeleteCertificates/{trainee_id?}', 'UserFeedbackController@admin_destroy')->where('trainee_id', '(.*)');;`

linked button in the view as following this

`<td>
   <a class="btn btn-danger" href="DeleteCertificates/{{ $item->trainee_id }}">Delete</a>
 </td>`

here is the error.[image]

can anyone suggest me why this getting error.

Comment: `UserFeedbackController` looks like the wrong thing to have a `where` function. Do you have a `UserFeedback` model defined?

Comment: ModelName::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->delete();

Comment: are you calling the where() method over a controller

Comment: yeah i fixed it.thanks u two.can anyone post it as a answer so that i can mark it perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling the controller name in place of model name, guess the modelname is

```
UserFeedback
```

so use this

```
UserFeedback::where('trainee_id','=',$trainee_id)->delete();
```